# Grid cannot load its state correctly

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a trouble at my grid when I load state.
The paging bar is being broken whenever I do this.

to understand please take a glance through this example: http://dojo.telerik.com/@doktoresperanto/oJiVu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to pass the data source aggregates because the footer template depends on them (your demo has an "undefined" error because of missing aggregates). Here is how:

```
grid.dataSource.query({"page":3,"pageSize":7, aggregate: grid.dataSource.aggregate() });
```

And a live demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@korchev/oDoPE

Comment: According to answer I have received just now. we can also use that way : grid.setOptions({dataSource: {pageSize:5, page:3}})